# How to create a new variable based on two categorical variables in R?

Tags: r, variables

I have two categorical variables a & b.

```
a = sample(0:1, size=10, replace=T )
b = sample(0:1, size=10, replace=T )
```

I want to create a new variable c, whose values depend on a & b in such a way:

```
c = vector(length=10)
c[a==1 & b==1] = 1
c[a==1 & b==0] = 2
c[a==0 & b==1] = 3
c[a==0 & b==0] = 4
```

Is there a simple function maybe from the base package that can do this?

I need to deal with creating a new variable based on multiple variables, each with multiple categories. So I am looking for an efficient solution other than the one I have just used.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is best to not create a variable named `c`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`interaction` does what you want, given the proper inputs:

```
> a
 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
> b
 [1] 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0

as.numeric(interaction(!b, !a))
## [1] 2 1 2 2 2 1 4 4 4 4
```

Equivalently:

```
as.numeric(interaction(!a, !b, lex.order=TRUE))
```

Or even:

```
as.numeric(as.factor(!a):as.factor(!b))
```

The `!` is to coerce the inputs to get the exact results that you get in your question (you want the input `1` values to appear before the input `0` values, which is reverse of the default factor ordering).

However, `interaction` is made to create factor interactions and will work on any factors (as will `:` if the inputs are already factors -- `interaction` coerces its input to `factor`).

`lex.order=TRUE` does not mean to sort, it means to increment trailing factors faster (in this case, this setting means the each value of `!b` is cycled through for each value of `!a`).

Comment: Are there any ways to implement this recursively if I have multiple factors I want to do it with?

Answer (score 0):

Here are two other options:

```
set.seed(1)
a = sample(0:1, size=10, replace=T )
b = sample(0:1, size=10, replace=T )

#Option 1
c = ifelse(a == 1 & b == 1, 1, 
       ifelse(a == 1 & b == 0, 2, 
              ifelse(a == 0 & b == 1, 3,4)
              )
       )
#Option 2
c2 = (a == 1 & b == 1) * 1 +
  (a == 1 & b == 0) * 2 +
  (a == 0 & b == 1) * 3 +
  (a == 0 & b == 0) * 4
```

Giving you:

```
> cbind(a,b,c,c2)
      a b c c2
 [1,] 1 1 1  1
 [2,] 1 0 2  2
 [3,] 1 1 1  1
 [4,] 0 1 3  3
 [5,] 0 0 4  4
 [6,] 1 1 1  1
 [7,] 0 0 4  4
 [8,] 1 0 2  2
 [9,] 0 1 3  3
[10,] 1 0 2  2
```